# Software Tool for collecting components in database

Tags: software

I have a lot of electrical components in the boxes. I would like to have information about parts in database. Do you use some software or you have any open source for it? I need something free easy tool not big one for paying monthly services for using it.

Comment: Check out PartKeepr. https://www.partkeepr.org/

Comment: Thanks, it looks very good. I expected something more ease as open source.

Comment: @MarianMinar That one by Klas appears to be open and you can install it on Apache and use it via a browser, from what I see. You just need your own site, which is modest in cost these days and has other value once you bite the bullet. I've not looked at the code, but if it uses dependency injection for the repository, you could perhaps burn off the code on a local machine and supply a different class/interface for the repository function and avoid MySQL. But it's not a Windows program. That's true.

Comment: @MarianMinar Are you looking for something running on a cell phone (android, ios, ??) Or something on a workstation or laptop computer? What's the goal? And if you can describe in detail what you need, that goes a long way in getting others to more readily help out.

Comment: Hello Jonk, Klas project is excellent for my purpose. I used virtual machine solution built at linux. It worked under Windows and all data are accessible by web browser. Version at virtual machine is little bit older but still work excellent. All my troubles are gone.